# specify directory for filehandler for log files

Tags: java, file, logging, handler, filehandler

```
Handler h = new FileHandler("MyDailyLogFile_" + sdf.format(date)
                    + ".log", true);
```

I am looking produce daily log file for my application. I have a run script in directory `home\lse\scripts` from which the application runs. This is where all the logs files get saved. The environment is UNIX. I would like to specify the log files to be saved in `home\lse\logs`. How do I specify the logs directory within `FileHandler()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html). Maybe you can specify this in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler h = new FileHandler("../logs/MyDailyLogFile_" + sdf.format(date)
                    + ".log", true);
```